# ssh into a Win 11 PC: Failed password

Tags: ssh, powershell, passwords, openssh

I mean to ssh
from a [*Win 10 (es-AR locale, LCID 11274) + PS 7.1.3 client (PC1)*]
to a [*Win 11 (en-US, LCID 1033) + OpenSSH server (PC2, with PS 5.1.22000)*].
I followed the usual procedure in PC2 to enable OpenSSH server, via Powershell (as I have successfully done before, albeit with Win 10 servers).

It appears my password is rejected.
I have seen several similar posts (listed below).
None of the solutions posted solved the problem.
I will list what I have tried, and post the relevant information.
I can provide any further details.

**How can I solve this?**

### In client PC1:

(I get essentially the same if I use `ssh -vvv user2@192.168.0.<server>` without the domain... is that expected?)

```
> ssh -vvv LAPTOP-ROOM1\user2@192.168.0.<server>
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\USER1/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\USER1/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for 192.168.0.<server>
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.0.<server> is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.<server> [192.168.0.<server>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/USER1/powershell/$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/USER1/powershell/$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/USER1/powershell/$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/USER1/powershell/$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.<server>:22 as 'LAPTOP-ROOM1\\user2'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:*******************************************
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/dev/null"
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.<server>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_fetch_identitylist: invalid format
debug1: Will attempt key: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
no such identity: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
LAPTOP-ROOM1\user2@192.168.0.<server>'s password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
LAPTOP-ROOM1\user2@192.168.0.<server>'s password:  <Ctrl>+C
```

### In server PC2:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
LAPTOP-ROOM1\user2

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WinEvent OpenSSH/Operational -Oldest | ft Message

Message
-------
sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.   
sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
sshd: Failed password for user2 from 192.168.0.<client> port 53884 ssh2
...
sshd: Connection closed by authenticating user user2 192.168.0.<client> port 60061 [preauth]
sshd: Authentication refused.
...


PS C:\Windows\system32> wevtutil qe OpenSSH/Operational /f:Text
...
Event[65]
  Log Name: OpenSSH/Operational
  Source: OpenSSH
  Date: 2022-09-06T18:57:42.6030000Z
  Event ID: 4
  Task: N/A
  Level: Information
  Opcode: Info
  Keyword: N/A
  User: S-1-5-18
  User Name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  Computer: LAPTOP-ROOM1
  Description:
sshd: Failed password for user2 from 192.168.0.<client> port 60277 ssh2
...

PS C:\Windows\system32> sshd.exe -ddd
debug2: load_server_config: filename __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 303
debug2: parse_server_config: config __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config len 303
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:34 setting PubkeyAuthentication yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:38 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:51 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/sshd_config:79 setting Subsystem sftp      sftp-server.exe
debug3: checking syntax for 'Match Group administrators'
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:**********************************
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:**********************************
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:**********************************
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 303
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Connection from 192.168.0.<client> port 54493 on 192.168.0.<server> port 22
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: spawning "C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\sshd.exe" -ddd -y
debug2: Network child is on pid 17880
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 4 config len 303
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 0000018CB5DE9790(99)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 7 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user LAPTOP-ROOM1\\\\user2 service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 303
debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user user2 host 192.168.0.<client> addr 192.168.0.<client> laddr 192.168.0.<server> lport 22
debug3: get_user_token - i am running as user2, returning process token
debug1: user user2 matched group list administrators at line 87
debug3: match found
debug3: reprocess config:88 setting AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for LAPTOP-ROOM1\\\\user2 [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 29.613ms, delaying 20.977ms (requested 6.324ms) [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user LAPTOP-ROOM1\\\\user2 service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=LAPTOP-ROOM1\\\\user2 devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 6.324ms (requested 6.324ms) [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user LAPTOP-ROOM1\\\\user2 service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 12 [preauth]
debug3: mm_auth_password: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_AUTHPASSWORD [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 13 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 12
debug1: Windows authentication failed for user: user2 domain: . error: 1326
debug3: mm_answer_authpassword: sending result 0
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 13
Failed password for LAPTOP-ROOM1\\user2 from 192.168.0.<client> port 54493 ssh2
debug3: mm_auth_password: user not authenticated [preauth]
debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 31.796ms, delaying 18.794ms (requested 6.324ms) [preauth]
```

### Contents of `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

### Other info

After removing `C:\Users\USER2\.ssh\known_hosts` and adding

```
Host 192.168.0.<server>
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

in `C:\Users\USER2\.ssh\config`, I see essentially the same, except for not being asked about the new server, and `known_hosts` not being created.

### Notes

1. In the server, with `sshd -vvv`, I see a line `get_passwd: LookupAccountName() failed: 1332.` I think it may be useful info. [This](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1254) may be relevant, but I am not sure how to interpret it.
2. I don't think any of the settings about keys has anything to de here, but just in case I mention I have 4 keys in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys`, but the output of `sshd -vvv` is only showing 3. As I understand, I don't have to do anything beyond adding the key to that file for it to be read.
3. I added `DefaultShell` under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH` with `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH /v DefaultShell /d C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.
4. This question is related to
   [ssh into a Win 11 PC: Authentication refused, Failed publickey](https://superuser.com/questions/1740325/ssh-into-a-win-11-pc-authentication-refused-failed-publickey)

### Related

1. [Cannot ssh into server with correct password](https://superuser.com/questions/1731437/cannot-ssh-into-server-with-correct-password)
2. [Password authentication is not working in ssh on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1569241/password-authentication-is-not-working-in-ssh-on-windows)
3. https://serverfault.com/questions/888350/windows-10-ssh-disable-password-authentication
4. [How do I find my username and servername for windows SSH server](https://superuser.com/questions/1661724/how-do-i-find-my-username-and-servername-for-windows-ssh-server)
5. [SSH into a passwordless windows 10 pc](https://superuser.com/questions/1698831/ssh-into-a-passwordless-windows-10-pc)
6. [OpenSSH not accepting my login password](https://superuser.com/questions/1522466/openssh-not-accepting-my-login-password)
7. https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1868
8. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-1326-when-you-change-domain-account-password-in-windows-a238729e-4b79-b9e2-ebfa-2967c91ef5bf

Comment: [Try recreating the key file.  Previous questions indicate the key file might be incorrectly formatted.](https://serverfault.com/questions/251876/debug1-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address-when-t)

Comment: I would also delete any known_hosts files on either system,  In other reading an issue with that file was also to blame for `C:/dev/tty  
 error:3` Are you by chance running Windows on a non-English locale?

Comment: I would also disable Strict Mode, it provides little harm as a test, provided this is all intranet traffic and you are not forwarding inbound traffic to the OpenSSH server.

Comment: @Ramhound - While I try recreating the key file, wouldn't it be a completely different issue?
If key authentication fails, when I try password authentication and it fails, is it of any relevance the (possible) issue with the key?

Comment: @Ramhound - I have added info to the OP on what I tried and updated output obtained, following your suggestions. I also changed from msys2 to PS7 in the client.
If locale is a possible source of the problem on its own, do you know how to check that?

Comment: You don’t know if your system locale is English? This user your trying to authenticate, is it an Administrator?

Comment: @Ramhound - I do know the locale in both systems, and I added that.
The user in the client is not an administrator:
<br>
`(New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)`
<br>
`False`.

Comment: Try changing the locale to `en-US`.  You mention something about "without the domain", so is the client machine connected to a Active Directory domain, and if so what is the exact syntax the client is using to authenticate the AD domain account? `C:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys` only applies to Administrator accounts, if the user is not an Administrator account, then their key CANNOT be placed in that folder.  Sadly, due to your delay in answering my question on Sept 6th, I lost all my research on this subject. You should try my Strict Mode suggestion

Comment: @Ramhound, if you have resolved the issue, let me know the solution.

Comment: @Bhuvan - I am not the author of this question, nor was there enough engagement from the author, to answer it

Comment: @sancho.s, if you have resolved the issue, let me know the solution

Comment: @Bhuvan - I don't recall what happened. Most likely, I couldn't gather all the information asked by Ramhound (who is an expert and always most willing to help) before I had to deal with my need in some other way, or simply leave it.
I guess had I solved it, I would have posted a comment / edited the OP.